# How to identify number of PDF viewers installed on my system using a Winforms application

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf

I have created a Winforms application. It contains functionality to open and view PDF files. When I am using the `Process.Start()` function to open the PDF file, the file is opened in the default PDF viewer set on my system.

My requirement is find out the number of installed PDF viewers and set the desired one to use manually in my code.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you requested, but may help you anyway.

The Windows "Right Click -> Open With..." dialogs shows programs that can be used to open a file. The programms shown there are saved in the current users registry

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts
```

This only shows the name of the programs and not a path to the respective application. The names however don't point to the applications executables. You will most likely find them on other places in the registry.

Comment: Thanks, But how to get this list in my C# program

Comment: .NET has all the tools needed to read from and write to the registry. I won't explain it here, you will find all the information you need if your search for C# and registry. Like this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3389/Read-write-and-delete-from-registry-with-C Good luck, sir!

Comment: Btw. if you _just_ want to show a pdf file, you could as well include a pdf viewer in your application, like `Pdfium Viewer`.

Comment: No, there multiple viewer i have installed.As per specific scenario or pdf complexity i want to change viewer. it will be manage by application

Comment: Ah okay. Good luck, Sir!